# Finding the Domain?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-writing, absolute-value

The set ${{x:\left|x+\frac{1}{x}\right|>6}}$ equals the set

**My Approach**

We know,IF $|f(x)| \geqslant a, \quad ;a>0$

then $f(x) \geqslant a \quad \cup \quad f(x) \leqslant-a$

$\frac{x^{2}+1}{x}> 6$ & $\frac{x^{2}+1}{x}<-6$

$\frac{x^{2}-6 x+1}{x}>0..........(1)$

$\frac{x^{2}+6 x+1}{x}<0$............(2)

$Using$ $Wavy$ $curve$ $method,$

From (1) I can find,
$x \in(0,3-2 \sqrt{2}) \cup(3+2 \sqrt{2}, \alpha)$

From (2) ,I can find,
$x \in(-\alpha,-3-2 \sqrt{2}) \cup(-3+2 \sqrt{2},0)$

*Next I am unable to find any common between them.*

Answer (score 1):

We have  $x\neq0$ and  $$x^2+1>6|x|$$ or
$$|x|^2-6|x|+1>0,$$ which is
$$|x|>3+2\sqrt2$$ or
$$|x|<3-2\sqrt2,$$ which gives the answer:
$$(-\infty,-3-2\sqrt2)\cup(-3+2\sqrt2,0)\cup(0,3-2\sqrt2)\cup(3+2\sqrt2,+\infty)$$

Comment: Was my approach wrong?

Comment: @RANCHO It's not wrong. Now you need to write the answer as I did.  I just think that my way is more quickly.

Comment: Can u please tell me, from my solution ,how to find the common domain from those two domains,I am getting no clue!

Comment: @RANCHO Just write $\cup$ between them. See the last line in my post.

Comment: got it! it is clear ,thank you

Comment: You are welcome, @RANCHO !